# Trying to determine if this is a load bearing wall

Tags: load-bearing

The wall in question is on the ground floor of a 2 story house, I've marked it in green. I've got 2 sketch ups for the ground floor(G) and one for the main floor(M). From what I can see, the floor joists are parallel to the wall in question, and it seems to line up with the closet doors on the floor above and not the wall itself. We're hoping to open the wall but leave about a foot on the side that connects to the exterior.
[Mainfloor](https://ibb.co/YBjGgx6)
[Ground floor](https://ibb.co/zFqVZh2)
[Ground floor](https://ibb.co/7WDxywS)
Thanks!